# Is it possible to use pjsua2 in python to use AudioMedia Memory/Buffer-based Playback Port in real time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm developing a SIP client using python, based on [pjsua2](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/). I have a custom Call class based on [python wrapper call](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/call.html) and my code is able to get an active connection. On my custom `onCallMediaState`, I have access to the Audio Conference Bridge:

```py
    def onCallMediaState(self, prm):
        """
        Manage call media state callbacks.

        - Autoconnect audio
        """
        ci = self.getInfo()

        logger.info("onCallMediaState", media_size=ci.media.size())
        self._print_call_info("onCallMediaState")

        for media_index, media in enumerate(ci.media):
            if media.type == pj.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
                if ci.stateText == "CONFIRMED":
                    """
                    It seems a bug with callbacks. CONFIRMED
                    is send at start and disconnect. So stop
                    record is manual, cannot use DISCONNECTD
                    """
                    logger.info("Call CONFIRMED")
```

At this point I can use `media_index` to record or play the audio incoming from the call. In example, for recording:

```py
    def record_call(self, media_index):
        """
        Record the audio incoming from call using default playback device
        """
        record_media = pj.Endpoint_instance().audDevManager().getCaptureDevMedia()
        audio_media = pj.AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(self.getMedia(media_index))
        port_id = audio_media.getPortId()
        rx_level = audio_media.getRxLevel()
        tx_level = audio_media.getTxLevel()
        filename = "file.wav"
        logger.info("Recording audio media", port_id=port_id, rx_level=rx_level, tx_level=tx_level)
        self._recorder = pj.AudioMediaRecorder()
        self._recorder.createRecorder(filename);
        self._is_recording = True
        record_media.startTransmit(self._recorder)
```

And a file.wav is created. Or for use default audio device:

```py
    def play_call(self, media_index):
        """
        Play the audio incoming from call using default playback device
        """
        playback_media = pj.Endpoint_instance().audDevManager().getPlaybackDevMedia()
        audio_media = pj.AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(self.getMedia(media_index))
        port_id = audio_media.getPortId()
        rx_level = audio_media.getRxLevel()
        tx_level = audio_media.getTxLevel()
        logger.info("Playing audio media", port_id=port_id, rx_level=rx_level, tx_level=tx_level)
        audio_media.startTransmit(playback_media)
```

Both examples work and according to [PjSUA2 Media documentation](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/media.html) and [Audio media documentation](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1AudioMedia.htm) it is possible transmit and receive audio, play and record WAV. But according with [pjsip Media Port documentation](https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__PORT.htm) other medias are possible. It seems that [SWIG wrapper](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html) do not support it.

Finally, my question, Is it possible to manage the audio frame in memory without record a wav file?

I do not want to write in the hard disk the audio, just use it in memory, and for this purpose I need the raw data directly. One workaround is to write a chunk wav file, and read it one by one, but this is a dirty solution with a big overhead. According to [Media flow documentation](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/media-flow) it is possible to get the callbacks, but I cannot find how to do this in Python. It doesn't exist the `typedef void *MediaPort` in the python wrapper to try to bypass the callbacks.

Comment: Hey, any updates on the question? could you find a solution to that? I would be also interested in the solution

Answer (score 3):

[pjsua2_demo.cpp](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/blob/master/pjsip-apps/src/samples/pjsua2_demo.cpp#L203) offers some hints on how to do this.

In python:

```py
class MyCall(pj.Call):

    def onCallMediaState(self, prm):
        ci = self.getInfo()
        for media_info in ci.media:
            if media_info.status == pj.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE:
                if media_info.type == pj.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
                    print("-----------------------------------> OnCallMediaState: Audio media is active")

                    fmt = pj.MediaFormatAudio()
                    fmt.type = pj.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
                    fmt.clockRate = 16000
                    fmt.channelCount = 1
                    fmt.bitsPerSample = 16
                    fmt.frameTimeUsec = 20000

                    self.med_port = MyAudioMediaPort()
                    self.med_port.createPort("med_port", fmt)
                    
                    media = pj.AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(self.getMedia(media_info.index))
                    media.startTransmit(self.med_port)


class MyAudioMediaPort(pj.AudioMediaPort):

    def onFrameRequested(self, frame):
        frame.type = pj.PJMEDIA_FRAME_TYPE_AUDIO

    def onFrameReceived(self, frame):
        # Process the incoming frame here
        print("frame received")
        print(frame.size)
        byte_data = [frame.buf[i] for i in range(frame.buf.size())]
        # Convert 1-byte values to signed 16-bit values
        int_data = [struct.unpack('<h', bytes(byte_data[i:i+2]))[0] for i in range(0, len(byte_data), 2)]

        print(int_data)
```

Please note; I'm just doing the bit-shift conversion so the numbers make sense. I haven't actually tested this, as most libraries will expect the unconverted little-endian buffer (you probably wont use it), but the output looks reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into the same, but for pjsua and not pjsua2. Originally pjsip does not support this for pjsua (not sure for pjsua2), but I found a project on GitHub that had a customization of pjproject 2.2 with buffered streaming called "UFAL-DSG/alex".

I ported the customization to python3 and pjproject 2.9 in "nicolaipre/python3-pjsip-memory-buffer".

I know it may not be of use to you for pjsua2, but maybe it can help someone else looking for something similar.